# Trying to get PIVOT working

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get a pivot table working. I have this based on examples I found online:

```
 select *
from (
 select CapVehicles.Cvehicle_DerText
  , NVDDictionaryOption.DO_Description as OptionText
  , [V12 2dr Touchtronic Auto]
  , [V12 Launch Edition 2dr Touchtronic Auto]
  , 1 as c
 from NVDStandardEquipment
 left join NVDDictionaryOption on NVDStandardEquipment.SE_OptionCode = NVDDictionaryOption.DO_OptionCode
 left join NVDDictionaryCategory on NVDDictionaryOption.DO_CatCode = NVDDictionaryCategory.DC_CatCode
 left join CapVehicles on NVDStandardEquipment.SE_Id = CapVehicles.CVehicle_Id
 where NVDStandardEquipment.SE_Id in (
   select distinct CVehicle_Id
   from CapVehicles
   left join CapDer on CapVehicles.CVehicle_Id = CapDer.CDer_Id
   where CapDer.cder_discontinued is null 
     and capvehicles.cvehicle_mantext = 'ASTON MARTIN' 
     and capvehicles.cvehicle_shortmodtext = 'DB11'
   ) and NVDStandardEquipment.SE_EffectiveTo is null
 ) as s
pivot (max(c) for Cvehicle_DerText in 
  ([V12 2dr Touchtronic Auto], [V12 Launch Edition 2dr Touchtronic Auto])) as pvt
```

My raw data looks like this, basically i'm trying to show in a grid which vehicles have which options, with the options as rows and the vehicles as columns.

```
V12 2dr Touchtronic Auto | Adaptive damping system
V12 2dr Touchtronic Auto | Cruise control  
V12 Launch Edition 2dr Touchtronic Auto | Adaptive damping system
V12 Launch Edition 2dr Touchtronic Auto | Cruise control
```

I get loads of errors with the above:

> Invalid column name 'V12 2dr Touchtronic Auto'.
>   Invalid column name 'V12 Launch Edition 2dr Touchtronic Auto'. 
>   The column name "V12 2dr Touchtronic Auto" specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument.
>   The column name "V12 Launch Edition 2dr Touchtronic Auto" specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument.
>   The column 'V12 2dr Touchtronic Auto' was specified multiple times for 'pvt'.

Answer (score 0):

I assume 'V12 2dr Touchtronic Auto', 'V12 Launch Edition 2dr Touchtronic Auto' is a values, not column names.
you should delete it from inner select.

Try this:

```
select *
from (
 select CapVehicles.Cvehicle_DerText
  , NVDDictionaryOption.DO_Description as OptionText
  , 1 as c
 from NVDStandardEquipment
 left join NVDDictionaryOption on NVDStandardEquipment.SE_OptionCode = NVDDictionaryOption.DO_OptionCode
 left join NVDDictionaryCategory on NVDDictionaryOption.DO_CatCode = NVDDictionaryCategory.DC_CatCode
 left join CapVehicles on NVDStandardEquipment.SE_Id = CapVehicles.CVehicle_Id
 where NVDStandardEquipment.SE_Id in (
   select distinct CVehicle_Id
   from CapVehicles
   left join CapDer on CapVehicles.CVehicle_Id = CapDer.CDer_Id
   where CapDer.cder_discontinued is null 
     and capvehicles.cvehicle_mantext = 'ASTON MARTIN' 
     and capvehicles.cvehicle_shortmodtext = 'DB11'
   ) and NVDStandardEquipment.SE_EffectiveTo is null
 ) as s
pivot (max(c) for Cvehicle_DerText in 
  ([V12 2dr Touchtronic Auto], [V12 Launch Edition 2dr Touchtronic Auto])) as pvt
```